# ICEConnectionState completed. still not able to get remote video

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I am using kurento one2one call for peer to peer connection.

I am using public stun server.

Am tring to connect to the one2one call as,
1. Peer A runnning in browser
2. Peer B runnning in kurento-android-client , a custom android app
3. Peer A makes the call. Sends offer and ICE candidates to Peer B.
4. Peer B accepts the call.
5. Creates offer and sends incomingCall Response as "accepted"
6. Sets Local Description.
7. Peer A get the response. Sets remote description.
8. Peer A sends "startCommunication" SDP answer.
9. Peer B adds the remote candidates to peer connection.
10. Peer B send the local candidates to Peer B.
11. Peer B adding remote stream.

In chrome://webrtc-internals, I couldnt get any errors. The final things is,
ICEConnectionState connected, ICEConnectionState completed.

But still i didnt get remote video in both browser and app. Only local streaming is available.

what could be the reason for this?

Comment: hii, do you find the solution why we are not getting remote video instead of establishing stun/turn server, worked on browser to browser perfectly.

Comment: No. But I found the reason, the code I used was using old version of Kurento. So, I need to use the version. But couldnt work on that afterwards. So still pending.